# Выборка из базы данных с группировкой по дате

Tags: mysql, timestamp

В базе данных есть таблица с курсами валют и поля с timestamp, но в один день данные собираются по нескольку раз, поэтому много дублей, как мне написать запрос чтобы выбирались данные с группировкой именно по дате, а не по дате-времени например за последний год

Comment: Под группировкой по дате вы подразумеваете таблицу со средними значениями (например) за 2016 год? или же применение какой то функции ко всем типам валют на определенную дату? Для выделения любого периода в mysql есть функции: `year()` `month()` `week()`...

Comment: Вам нужны курсы на конец каждого дня?

Comment: Вопрос уже решен SELECT * FROM currency WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND chcode = ? GROUP BY date, chcode

Comment: Вы могли опубликовать собственный ответ и объявить его решением. Это нормальная практика на S.O. А вот дописывать ответ в вопрос НЕ рекомендованный путь.

Comment: Так и сделал спсб

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил задачу следующим SQL запросом

```
SELECT * 
FROM currency 
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
  AND chcode = ? 
GROUP BY date, chcode
```

Answer (score 2):

Диапазон timestamp:

```
$at = strtotime('25-04-2016'); //1461535200
$to = strtotime('26-04-2016'); //1461621600
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp >= $at AND timestamp < $to
```

Диапазон даты:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2016-05-20'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
timestamp >= '2016-05-20 00:00:00' AND timestamp <= '2016-05-20 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Псб, а если так? WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR))

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться оператором `GROUP BY`, по календарному полю, которое пропущено через MySQL-функцию `DATE()`

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  DATE(created_at)
```

Однако, лучше всего избавиться от дублей, просто добавив уникальный индекс для поля даты и используя ключевое слово `IGNORE` в операторе `INSERT`, чтобы игнорировать вставки дубликатов.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что несколько записей в день это ошибка? Курс может реально меняться несколько раз в день.

Comment: Потому что я с сайта ЦБ беру он раз в день устанавливается, динамический меня не интересует

Comment: @АнтонВеселов Ок, тогда. Хорошо бы вам внести это в текст вопроса.